# How to check if module import fails and output relvant error?

Tags: python-3.x

New to python

I want to do this:

```
def imp_modules(module):
    try: 
       import module 
    except moduleName as failedModule: 
       print('Module ' + failedModule + ' failed to import ...')
       sys.exit(1)
```

That is an example of what I want to achieve. I want all the modules I am importing to go through that function. I don't want to have any `import module_name` outside that function.

Can this be achieved with a solution that is windows/linux compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to except a specific error, `ModuleNotFoundError`. Also, to import module from it's name, use importlib:

```py
import importlib
def imp_modules(module_name):
    try: 
       globals()[module_name] = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    except ModuleNotFoundError as err_message: 
       failedModule = err_message.msg.split("'")[1]
       print(f"Module '{failedModule}' failed to import ...")
       sys.exit(1)
#USAGE:
imp_modules("module_name")
```

You could also have the function iterate over all the modules to import:

```py
import importlib
def imp_modules(*module_names):
    for module_name in module_names:
      try: 
         globals()[module_name] = importlib.import_module(module_name)
      except ModuleNotFoundError as err_message: 
         failedModule = err_message.msg.split("'")[1]
         print(f"Module '{failedModule}' failed to import ...")
         sys.exit(1)
#USAGE:
imp_modules("module_one_name","module_two_name", ...)
```

Comment: hey. what is the `globals()[module_name]` doing ?

Comment: `globals()[module_name]` is adding a global variable under the name of the module. Its not *that* pythonic, but it works well.